# Windows crashes not being reported

Tags: windows-7, crash, windows-error-reporting

(This is on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.) Windows usually pops up a window when a program crashes and tells you that it's investigating the issue. It often asks to send information to Microsoft to help future troubleshooting as well. See below for a sample screenshot.

Recently, a box popped up asking if I want to automatically send information to Microsoft on each crash, and I accidentally clicked yes. Now the error message no longer pops up at all--programs are crashing silently. (I know that they're crashing because I'm troubleshooting a specific program and no box pops up.)

How can I disable the automatic sending of information to Microsoft and get my crash notification back?

[image: crash report example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just navigate to:

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Action Center\Problem Reporting
>   Settings

and select the option:

- **Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for solutions**

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The following describes the options:

> - Choosing Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for    solutions will keep error reporting enabled but will prevent Windows
>     7 from automatically notifying Microsoft about the issue. If your
>     concern about error reporting is only privacy related, this is the
>     best option for you
> - Choosing Never check for solutions will fully disable error reporting    in Windows 7.

[Source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disable-error-reporting-windows-7.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (that I probably should've done before posting). I searched Control Panel for "error reporting", then clicked the link titled "Choose how to check for solutions". Then I selected "Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for solutions". The crash messages have reappeared.